# Setting up train/test split for use in Conv neural network

Tags: python, conv-neural-network

I have a NN I'd like to use here:

```
model = keras.models.Sequential([
    keras.layers.Conv2d(64, 7, activation="relu", padding="same",
                        input_shape = [40, 40, 1]),
    keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(2),
    keras.layers.Conv2D(128, 3, activation="relu", padding="same"),
    keras.layers.Conv2D(128, 3, activation="relu", padding="same"),
    keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(2),
    keras.layers.Conv2D(256, 3, activation="relu", padding="same"),
    keras.layers.Conv2D(256, 3, activation="relu", padding="same"),
    keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(2),
    keras.layers.Flatten(),
    keras.layers.Dense(128, activation="relu"),
    keras.layers.Dropout(0.5)
    keras.layers.Dense(64, activation="relu"),
    keras.layers.Dropout(0.5)
    keras.layers.Dense(8, activation="softmax")
])
```

But I'm not sure how to set up the train/test split for it.. I have a dataframe with columns:

```
df['matrices']
df['class']
```

There are 25k instances, so 25k matrices and then 8 "types" of matrices, where the elements of the matrices create different sorts of shapes when viewed as an image. Each matrix has its corresponding type indexed in the 'class' column. Each is a 40x40 matrix array of type uint8, and has no depth. All elements of the matrix are either a 0, 1, or 2.

So the input shape of the NN is rightly 40x40x1, but I am at a loss right now for how to set things up around it with the information I have.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This answer is quite basic and is intended just to get you started. There is much more to training and testing a model, as well as data preparation for training.

To split the data and train and test a model, you could do something like this:

```
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(df['matrices], df['class'], random_state=42, test_size=.2)
model.fit(x=X_train, y=y_train)
```

The random_state makes your data split reproducible for future experiments.
You may consider rescaling your matrices to values between 0 and 1.
You may need to check the batch_size, epochs and callbacks parameters in the .fit method according to your application and hardware specs.[Tensorflow model.fit documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/Model#fit)

You can test the model using the test split from your data:

```
model.evaluate(x=X_test, y=y_test)
```

That returns the loss value and metrics values for the model in test mode.